# Python's nested classes

Tags: python, class, oop, nested

I'm having trouble with Python's nested classes. Here's how I have the code set up:

```
class Player:

    class Doll2:
        def __init__(self, stats):
            self.role = stats[0]
            self.level = float(stats[1])
            self.hp = float(stats[2])
            self.strength = float(stats[3])
            self.skill = float(stats[4])
            self.agility = float(stats[5])
            self.constitution = float(stats[6])
            self.charisma = float(stats[7])
            self.intelligence = float(stats[8])
            self.armor = float(stats[9])
            self.damage_min = float(stats[10])
            self.damage_max = float(stats[11])
            self.resilience = float(stats[12])
            self.critical = float(stats[13])
            self.block = float(stats[14])
            self.healing = float(stats[15])
            self.threat = float(stats[16])


    def __init__(self, name, server, province):
        stats2 = get_info_doll(province, server, name, "2")
        self.Doll2(stats2)

player1 = Player("Username", "us", "1")

print(player1.Doll2.hp)
```

And here is the error that I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: class Doll2 has no attribute 'hp'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably don't want to set things up like this ultimately. For instance, if you ever add a new class that has all these same stats, you'll just have to retype them! Move those stats into their own mixin or a base class that multiple things inherit from.

Comment: I dont have to retype anything, I have functions set up for that so that's not a problem, but could you add a code sample of what you mean? I'm eager to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.Doll2(stats2)` creates an instance of Doll2 but doesn't bind it to any attribute of `player1`. You need to do:

```
 def __init__(self, name, server, province):
        stats2 = get_info_doll(province, server, name, "2")
        self.attributename = self.Doll2(stats2)
```

Comment: It actually does instantiate it, but does not bind it to any attribute.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, just so simple problem and I've been wondering for a good hour for now, I'll accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 2):

`hp` is an attribute of instance (not of class)
try this:

```
class Player:

    class Doll2:
        def __init__(self, stats):
            # ... more assignments
            self.hp = float(stats[2])
            # ... more assignments


    def __init__(self, name, server, province):
        stats2 = get_info_doll(province, server, name, "2")
        self.doll2 = self.Doll2(stats2)  # create instance of Doll2

player1 = Player("Username", "us", "1")
print(player1.doll2.hp)  # using instance instead of class
```

The important lines is:

`self.doll2 = self.Doll2(stats2)`

and

`print(player1.doll2.hp)`